how to validated/check outer for customer input , max 3 times, and then go disconnect or other flow in amazon connect
i am trying to implement a menu where 3 times customer allowed to enter if wrong value else disconnect.
i am trying to implement a menu where 3 times customer allowed to enter value if wrong all time disconnect call or any time provide correct input take to BAU flow.
